# How to print training progress in Tensorflow DNNClassifier estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I want to train a model with `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` in a Kaggle notebook environment where the internet is blocked. Therefore, I cannot use Tensorboard to monitor the progress. So instead, I want to log the progress in the standard output (similar to when we call `fit` method on a Keras model) but I couldn't make it work.

What I have tried so far is set logging levels to `INFO` and passing a `tf.estimator.RunConfig` instance to the estimator. `RunConfig` has a `log_step_count_steps` attribute with default value = 100 which seems to be related to what I am looking for, but It does not work. Here is part of the code:

```
import logging;
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

config = tf.estimator.RunConfig()
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns = feature_columns,
    hidden_units = [128, 64],
    n_classes = 2,
    config = config
)

classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
```

I use Tensorflow version `1.11.0-rc1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying so many solutions, I finally figured out that all the code in the question is necessary such as setting log levels to INFO and passing a `RunConfig` object to `DNNClassifier`, but due to a bug in Kaggle kernel notebooks, before training the classifier we first need to log something arbitrary to make Tensorflow logging work in Kaggle! for example:

```
logging.info('I am info')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set required values in RunConfig using replace.

```
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig().replace(keep_checkpoint_max = 5, 
                    log_step_count_steps=20, save_checkpoints_steps=200)
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns = feature_columns,
    hidden_units = [128, 64],
    n_classes = 2,
    config = config
)

classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
```

The above code should log loss after every 20 steps.

Comment: Thanks, but I think `RunConfig` constructor has default values for the parameters you mentioned as well and there is no need to use `replace` method. anyway, as I mentioned in the question, it seems that the issue is from somewhere else.